# The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused in kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3d

I installed `kubectl` and `k3d` after following these official documentations ([k3d](https://k3d.io/v5.4.9/) and [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/)).
I created a cluster with the following command:

```
k3d cluster create mycluster
```

Then I ran this command:

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

Which gave me this error message:
`The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

After searching I found that the file `/etc/kubernetes` wasn't created (which means no `admin.conf` file was created), and the folder `~/.kube` also doesn't exist.
PS: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52262765/15368012) to understand

Here are the versions of `k3d` and `kubectl`

```
$ k3d version
k3d version v5.4.9
k3s version v1.25.7-k3s1 (default)
```

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.25.2
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Kubeadm was properly installed or not?. The command `kubeadm version` helps you to know the running status of kubeadm.

**Note :** If you can see the kubeadm version number, your kubeadm was installed properly.

And also run `kubeadm init` to initialize the control plane on your machine and create the necessary configuration files. See [Kubernetes Community forum](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/facing-connection-issue-to-localhost-8080-while-using-the-cmd-kubectl-version/22644) issue for more information.

> You may haven’t set the kubeconfig environment variable and the
> `.kube/config` file is not exported to the user $HOME directory.

See **Nijo Luca’s** [blog](https://k21academy.com/docker-kubernetes/the-connection-to-the-server-localhost8080-was-refused/) on **k21 academy**  for more information, which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks a lot, my environment was missing the `kubeadm` package.